# What are the names of four oceans according to Hinduism scriptures?

Tags: mahabharata, earth, geography

[Vaisampayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaisampayana) in his conversation with [Janamejaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janamejaya) told that there are four oceans on earth

> "Vaisampayana said, 'Asked by thee, I shall tell thee all about the
>   heroic-kings in Puru's line, all equal unto Indra in prowess,
>   possessing great affluence and commanding the respect of all for their
>   accomplishments.
>
> "Puru had by his wife Paushti three sons, Pravira, Iswara, and
>   Raudraswa, all of whom were mighty car-warriors. Amongst them, Pravira
>   was the perpetuator of the dynasty. Pravira had by his wife Suraseni a
>   son named Manasyu. And the latter of eyes like lotus-petals had his
>   sway over the **whole Earth bounded by the four seas**. And Manasyu
>   had for his wife Sauviri.
>
> [[SECTION XCIV, Sambhava Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01095.htm)

---

Although oceans are currently classified in to five, they are classified as four in history. (There is only one big ocean on the earth). This fact can be observed from the following two sources

[Source 1](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/howmanyoceans.html)

> Historically, there are four named ocean basins: the Atlantic,
>   Pacific, Indian, and Arctic. However, most countries - including the
>   United States - now recognize the Southern (Antarctic) as the fifth
>   ocean basin. The Pacific, Atlantic, and Indian are the most commonly
>   known.

[Source 2](https://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/infopage/oceans.htm)

> For many years only (4) four oceans were officially recognized, and
>   then in the spring of 2000, the International Hydrographic
>   Organization established the Southern Ocean, and determined its
>   limits. Those limits include all water below 60 degrees south, and
>   some of it, like the Arctic Ocean, is frozen.

---

**Do any scripture mention the names of the four oceans told by Vaisampayana?**

Comment: " Chatussagara paryantham.. " so goes the Sloka in Hindu rituals